# When I try to stream a few few Tweets, I only get the 403 response

Tags: tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to perform real time sentiment analysis using Twitter, but instead of Tweets I only get the number 403.

```
from tweepy import Stream, StreamListener
import json 
from textblob import TextBlob
import re
import csv


class Listener(StreamListener):
   def on_data(self, data):
      raw_tweets = json.loads(data)
      print(raw_tweets['text'])

   def on_error(self, status):
      print(status)


auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)

twitter_stream = Stream(auth, Listener())
twitter_stream.filter(track = ['Trump'])
```

When I do this, as said before I only get the number 403 several times.

It is worth mentioning I got elevated access

Comment: Are you using a Twitter Developer App created on or after 2022-04-29?

Comment: After that date.

Answer (score 1):

New Twitter Developer Apps:

> will not be able to gain access to v1.1 statuses/sample and v1.1 statuses/filter

https://twittercommunity.com/t/deprecation-announcement-removing-compliance-messages-from-statuses-filter-and-retiring-statuses-sample-from-the-twitter-api-v1-1/170500

You'll have to use Twitter API v2.

Answer (score 0):

403 is the HTTP error code for "Forbidden". You can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

You must be doing something incorrectly when authenticating with the Twitter API.

Comment: I think you may have mixed up 401 and 403. If you are talking about doing something incorrectly when authenticating, 401 should be the "expected" response code. 403 is more about you successfully authenticate yourself, but you have some permission/authorization issue.