# Twitter API: Stream encountered HTTP error: 403

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to use the Twitter API in Python. I got elevated access, set up my app in the Developer Portal, and authenticated OAuth 1.0.

When I write code I always receive the following error: Stream encountered HTTP error: 403. What am I doing wrong?

````
import tweepy 

api_key = "" 
api_key_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

stream = tweepy.Stream(api_key,api_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
stream.filter(track=["President"])```
````

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Twitter API v2 for this (Tweepy supports it, but you will need to update your code). Regardless of elevated access, after April 29 2022, new applications can no longer access v1.1 streaming.

New Twitter Developer Apps:

> will not be able to gain access to v1.1 statuses/sample and v1.1
> statuses/filter

https://twittercommunity.com/t/deprecation-announcement-removing-compliance-messages-from-statuses-filter-and-retiring-statuses-sample-from-the-twitter-api-v1-1/170500

Also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72252710/when-i-try-to-stream-a-few-few-tweets-i-only-get-the-403-response/72325881#72325881).

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks. But what is wrong with my code for Twitter API v2? How do I have to change it? I followed examples in the documentation.

Comment: You need to use the [`tweepy.StreamingClient` class](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streaming.html) instead of `tweepy.Stream`.